# Nielsen & Chuang, Problem 2.2 — Properties of the Schmidt number

Tags: linear-algebra

I started reading the Nielsen & Chuang's [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information). I got stuck by the last question of Problem 2.2. I got the other problems, but I can't see this one. I guess it's not really difficult, but as I am new in this field, some help will be nice. :)

Problem statement:

> Suppose $|\psi\rangle $ is a pure state of a composite system with components $A$ and $B$, such that: $$|\psi\rangle = \alpha \rvert \phi \rangle + \beta \rvert \gamma \rangle$$
> Prove that:
> $$ \operatorname{Sch}(\psi) \geq | \operatorname{Sch}(\phi) - \operatorname{Sch}(\gamma)|$$
> where $\operatorname{Sch}(x)$ is the Schmidt number of the pure state labeled $x$.

My attempt:

Here is what I tried. Let's assume that $ \operatorname{Sch}(\phi) > \operatorname{Sch}(\gamma)$. If we write the Schmidt decomposition of $\phi$ and $\gamma$:
\begin{align*}
| \phi \rangle &= \sum_i \phi_i | a_i^{\phi} \rangle | b_i^{\phi} \rangle\\
| \gamma \rangle &= \sum_i \gamma_i | a_i^{\gamma} \rangle | b_i^{\gamma} \rangle,
\end{align*}
we can then calculate the partial trace of $\psi$ regarding component $A$:
$$
\rho  \equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(| \psi \rangle \langle \psi |) = |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + |\beta|^2 \rho_{\gamma \gamma} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} + \bar{\alpha} \beta \rho_{\gamma \phi},
$$

where:

$$
\rho_{\phi \phi} \equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(| \phi \rangle \langle \phi |) = \sum_i \phi_i^2 | a_i^{\phi} \rangle  \langle a_i^{\phi} | \\
\rho_{\gamma \gamma} \equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(| \gamma \rangle \langle \gamma |) = \sum_i \gamma_i^2 | a_i^{\gamma} \rangle  \langle a_i^{\gamma} | 
\\
\rho_{\phi \gamma}\equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(| \phi \rangle \langle \gamma |) = \sum_i \phi_i | a_i^{\phi} \rangle  \sum_j \gamma_j \langle b_j^{\gamma} | b_i^{\phi} \rangle \langle a_j^{\gamma} | \\
\rho_{\gamma \phi}\equiv \operatorname{tr}_B(| \gamma \rangle \langle \phi |) = \sum_i \gamma_i | a_i^{\gamma} \rangle  \sum_j \phi_j \langle b_j^{\phi} | b_i^{\gamma} \rangle \langle a_j^{\phi} |.
$$

It can be seen that $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\phi \gamma})$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\phi})$, and similarly that $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\gamma \phi})$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\gamma})$. We define $ P_{\gamma} $ the projector onto $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\gamma})$ and
$$
P_{\gamma}^{\perp} = I - P_{\gamma}
$$
the projection onto the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{Im}(\rho_{\gamma})$. As $\operatorname{Sch}(\gamma)  < \operatorname{Sch}(\phi)$, the subspace corresponding to $P_{\gamma}^{\perp}$ is not reduced to the zero vector.
We end up with:
$$
\rho = P_{\gamma}( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + |\beta|^2 \rho_{\gamma \gamma} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} + \bar{\alpha} \beta \rho_{\gamma \phi} ) + P_{\gamma}^{\perp} ( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} ).
$$

As the subspaces corresponding to the two defined projectors are orthogonal:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{rank}(\rho) &= \operatorname{rank}(P_{\gamma}( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + |\beta|^2 \rho_{\gamma \gamma} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} + \bar{\alpha} \beta \rho_{\gamma \phi} ))\\
&+ \operatorname{rank}(P_{\gamma}^{\perp} ( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} )) \\
&\geq \operatorname{rank}(P_{\gamma}^{\perp} ( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} )),
\end{align*}
I was hoping to conclude by claiming that:
$$
\operatorname{rank}(P_{\gamma}^{\perp} ( |\alpha|^2 \rho_{\phi \phi} + \alpha \bar{\beta} \rho_{\phi \gamma} )) \geq \operatorname{Sch}(\phi) - \operatorname{Sch}(\gamma),
$$
but it is not correct, as I find counterexamples. Therefore I don't think that I am following the right track.

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/problem-2-2-in-nielsen-chuang-properties-of-the-schmidt-number